# Calling events on PLC Tag datachage in C#

Tags: c#, events, timer, plc

I need to read the value from PLC and display it in a form whenever the PLC Tag value changes.

There will list of tags which I need to monitor. Whenever a TAG value changes i need to call a function(different functions for each tag).

This is what I have done so far for capturing the Tag value change..

After connecting to PLC, i ll create the LIST of tags.

Read TAG values in timer.

While reading i ll check with OLDVALUES tag, if there is any change in value I ll raise an event.

This is working fine with 4 or 5 tags. When the Tag count is more, say 100, some of the Tag change events are not firing..

This is what so far I have done..

```
 public delegate void DataChangedEventHandler(string TagName, string NewValue);
    private Timer tmr = new Timer();

    public event DataChangedEventHandler OnDataChanged;
    private void StartTimer(DataTable dt)
    {
        AddTagList(dt);
        SetInitialVales();
        tmr.Tick += timerticks;
        tmr.Interval = 250;
        tmr.Enabled = true;
        tmr.Start();
    }
    private void StopTimer()
    {
        tmr.Enabled = false;
        tmr.Stop();
    }
```

I ll add the list of tags..

```
    private List<string> TagValues = new List<string>();
    private List<string> oldValues = new List<string>();
    private List<string> newValues = new List<string>();
    private void AddTagList(DataTable dt)
    {
        int ILoop = 0;

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            TagValues.Add((string)row["Path"]);
            ILoop = ILoop + 1;
        }
    }
```

To set the initial values of the Tags.

```
private void SetInitialVales()
    {
        int iLoop = 0;
        foreach (string vals in TagValues)
        {
            var rd = ReadTag(vals);
            oldValues.Add(rd.ToString());
            newValues.Add(rd.ToString());
            iLoop = iLoop + 1;
        }
        //newValues = oldValues
    }
```

and the main datachange part.

```
     private void timerticks(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        int iLoop = 0;
        foreach (string vals in TagValues)
        {
            oldValues[iLoop] = ReadTag(vals).ToString();
            if (oldValues[iLoop] != newValues[iLoop])
            {
                newValues[iLoop] = oldValues[iLoop];
                if (OnDataChanged != null)
                {
                    OnDataChanged(vals, newValues[iLoop]);
                }
            }
            iLoop = iLoop + 1;
        }
    }
```

My Queries:

1.What will happen if a event is raised while already raised event is still in progress(sub procedure is not completed)?? Is because of this reason I am missing some datachange events??

2.How to raise a raise a event automatically whenever the member of LIST value changes??

3.Any other better method to handle the timer-read-raiseevent?

Comment: Imagine what happens when a tag turns on and back off in less than 250 milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks. that we've taken care. None of the tags behaves like that..

Comment: That's unusual.  What *do* they behave like?  Are they guaranteed on for a second?  What happens if your code takes more than a second when you have a lot of tags?  Or is it latched so that no matter how long your code takes, it always sees the tag turned on?

Comment: No the tags are momentary. However the program is written such that none of them toggles with in 1 sec. but however i fail here //What happens if your code takes more than a second when you have a lot of tags?//.. How to handle this issue? **What will happen if a event is raised while already raised event is still in progress(sub procedure is not completed)?? Is because of this reason I am missing some datachange events??**

Comment: What PLC is this?  What software?  Most of them already have data change events built into the SDK and tag servers (with the bonus that they are generally well programmed as such).  Why are you re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: @J... It is Mitsubishi PLC. I converted old VB MXComponents to .NET. In that there is no inbuilt Datachange event.. Is there any other software (NOt OPC) for Mitsubishi like Libnodave for siemens? .NET version of MXCompenents available?

Comment: @Olivarsham there are not any (not OPC) components that I know of.  OPC is really the way to do things for manufacturers with rubbish in-house components.  Hans has the right idea, in any case. A dedicated thread is an absolute necessity.

Comment: @J... Thanks. I ll go with Hans' idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What will happen if a event is raised while already raised event is still in progress

The event won't be raised, not until your code is done executing the previous one.  Clearly you'll run into trouble when the events you fire take too long, longer than 1 second.  The more tags you have, or the more of them can change within one scan, the greater the odds that these events take more than 1 second and thus miss a tag change.

You'll need to de-couple the scanning from the event processing.  You can do so with a worker thread that does nothing but check for tag changes in a loop.  And if it sees any, put a update notification in a thread-safe queue.  Another thread, like your UI thread, can empty the queue and process the notifications.  The queue now acts as a buffer, providing enough storage to be able to keep up with a sudden burst of tag changes.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be better to create a class with old-new value in it and then a map with the tag as key to access the old-new instance?

It seems otherwise you have a lot of things floating around that need to be kept synched.

Comment: Can u please post some samples or elaborate it?? You mean to say to create a separate class for each tag with their values as properties??